# jQuery Mobile Preload CSS Background Images on 'pageinit' Event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating a Web App using JQM 1.1.0; this Web App uses the [Multi Page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html) JQM style with all pages contained in one HTML page. On the 'pageinit' event I have a delegate that takes some JSON data, combines it with a [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) template and populates the page; these pages are basic HTML with all images populated via css background-images.

Everything works as expected, however JQM doesn't seem to preload (no loading spinner) the css background-images prior to the page transition which is causing the images to load in randomly after the page has already been shown.

I've looked through the [JQM documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/) and haven't been able to find a way to force the preload of the images.

Also, I've also looked at CSS Image Pre-Loaders, but these cause the Web App to take a long time to load.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of research i was unable to find a stable cross-browser method on handling this. I may have overlooked something and would welcome an alternative answer if someone comes up with one.

For anyone facing the same problem, I ended up using a [CSS Image Preloader](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_automatically_preload_images_from_css_with_jquery/) and instead of attaching it to the `$(document).ready()` event, placed it on the `$(window).load()` event so that the images load in the background **AFTER** the first page of the Web App has loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $.preloadCssImages();
});
```

I hope this helps someone!